# Want to show a message on mouse hover on a date in the calender

Tags: asp.net

I have used the following .net code. Which shows the holiday date which I store in database. But i want to show some message when I hover the mouse on the date.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
string connection = @"server=TOPHAN-PC; Database=Tophan;uid=sa;pwd=123";
SqlConnection con = null;
protected DataSet dsHolidays;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{

    con = new SqlConnection(connection);
    Calendar1.VisibleDate = DateTime.Today;
    FillHolidayDataset();
}
}

protected void FillHolidayDataset()
{
DateTime firstDate = new DateTime(Calendar1.VisibleDate.Year,    Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month, 1);
DateTime lastDate = GetFirstDayOfNextMonth();
dsHolidays = GetCurrentMonthData(firstDate, lastDate);
}

protected DateTime GetFirstDayOfNextMonth()
{
int monthNumber, yearNumber;
if (Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month == 12)
{
    monthNumber = 1;
    yearNumber = Calendar1.VisibleDate.Year + 1;
}
else
{
    monthNumber = Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month + 1;
    yearNumber = Calendar1.VisibleDate.Year;
}
DateTime lastDate = new DateTime(yearNumber, monthNumber, 1);
return lastDate;
}

protected DataSet GetCurrentMonthData(DateTime firstDate, DateTime lastDate)
{
DataSet dsMonth = new DataSet();
try
{            
    //ConnectionStringSettings cs;
    //cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"];
    //String connString = cs.ConnectionString;
    //SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);

    String query = "SELECT CDate FROM calender  WHERE CDate >= @firstDate AND  CDate  <@lastDate";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstDate",
        firstDate));
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastDate", lastDate));

    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCommand);
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dsMonth);                       
}
catch
{ }
return dsMonth;
}
protected void Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender,MonthChangedEventArgs e)
{
FillHolidayDataset();
}
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
try
{
    DateTime nextDate;
    if (dsHolidays != null)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dsHolidays.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            nextDate = (DateTime)dr["CDate"];
            if (nextDate == e.Day.Date)
            {
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch
{ }
}
}
```

By using this code,I find out that it highlighted the date with the color but I want some message when I move the mouse on the Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsHolidays.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        nextDate = (DateTime)dr["CDate"];
        if (nextDate == e.Day.Date)
        {
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;
        e.Cell.ToolTip = "my tool tip";
        }
    }
```

hope this is clear.

Comment: No,I have tried it,but it won't work.It won't show the message. @Ratna

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (dsHolidays != null)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dsHolidays.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            nextDate = (DateTime)dr["CDate"];
            if (nextDate == e.Day.Date)
            {
e.Cell.ToolTip ="Add Message Here";
 e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
 e.Cell.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
}
}
```